# search for name of form field

Tags: php

I need to grab for the name for a input field.

All of them start with `inf_custom_InvitationCode` and they have a number appended to the end of them.

`inf_custom_InvitationCode0`

`inf_custom_InvitationCode1`

and so on. They could be different depending on the form.

How can I search for this and grab the data?

Comment: What do you mean grab? Is this PHP code? What does `print_r($_POST)` look like?

Comment: Well it was tagged as php was it not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fields are named 'inf_custom_InvitationCode###' and you control the source of the data being submitted to your form, you may be better off changing the code that creates the client-side form to name the input fields 'inf_custom_InvitationCode[]' (all of them can use that same name).
If you do this, PHP will take all the input values and add them as a single key to the $_REQUEST (and $_GET or $_POST)) array, which you can then use as you would any array.

Otherwise, you [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php#106973) contains something that does something like what you want to use.